# Find the power series representation and interval of convergence for the function

Tags: calculus

Find the power series representation and interval of convergence for the function $ \ f(x)=\frac{3}{2+x} \ $

**Answer:**

$f(x)=\frac{3}{x+2}=\frac{3}{2} (1+\frac{x}{2})^{-1}=\frac{3}{2} (1-\frac{x}{2}+(\frac{x}{2})^2-(\frac{x}{2})^3+..........) \ =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3}{2} (-1)^n (\frac{x}{2})^n $

The series  converges if $ \ |\frac{x}{2}|<1 \ \Rightarrow |x|<2 \ $

Thus the interval of convergence is $ -2<x<2 \ $

**Am I right so far?**

Comment: Yes, quite right.

Comment: what would be the case if $ \ f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{-2}{x-2} \ $ ? How to find the series in this case ?

Comment: Near   which point?

Comment: That is done. But I can not find out the interval of convergence of the series $ \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (16)^n x^{4n+5} \ $

Comment: Rewrite is as $x^5\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (x^4)^n$ and use Hadamard's formula.

Comment: where is gone $ \ (16)^n \ $ ?

Comment: How to use Hadamard formula?

Comment: I mistyped the formula. Add  $16^n$ and calculate $\limsup (a_n)^{1/n}$.

Comment: $ \frac{1}{R}=\lim \ \sup ((16 x^4)^n)^{1/n}  \ = \lim \ \sup 4x^2 $  Therefore, $ | x^5 \times 4x^2|=|4x^6|<1 \ $ But the what to do ?

Comment: There should be no $x$ in the limit sup. B.t.w., the code for the limit sup is simply `\limsup`

Comment: please help this because I can not fix it right now.

Comment: Is it $ \ | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=|\frac{(16x^4)^{n+1}}{(16x^4)^n} |=|16x^4|<1 \ \Rightarrow |x|<1/2 \ $

Comment: I've posted a sketch. Is that clearer?

Comment: The ratio test also works. Hadamard's formula is the most general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the series as $\; \sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^n 16^n x^{4n+5}= x^5\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^n 16^n(x^4)^n$.

The radius of convergence of the power series (setting $x^4=u$) is given by
$$\frac1R=\limsup_n\,\bigl(16^n\bigr)^{\tfrac1n}=16,$$
so the given power series converges if
$$ x^4<\frac1{16}\iff |x|<\frac12.$$